# How to scan values from each words based on tables and then calculate it And Make The VSM (Vector Space Model) From It

Tags: matlab, text-mining

Say that I have a table that contains probabilities from each words from another table. This Table has 2 classes; *actual* and *non_actual*. I will name it *master_table*

```
 actual = [0.5;0.4;0.6;0.75;0.23;0.96;0.532]; %sum of the probabilities is 1.     
actual + non_actual = 1
non_actual = [0.5;0.6:0.4;0.25;0.77;0.04;0.468];
words = {'finn';'jake';'iceking';'marceline';'shelby';'bmo';'naptr'};
master_table = table(actual,non_actual,...
'RowNames',words)
```

And then I have a table that contains sentences. I will name it T2

```
sentence = {'finn marceline naptr';'jake finn simon marceline haha';'jake finn finn jake iceking';'bmo shelby shelby finn naptr';'naptr naptr jake finn bmo shelby'}
T2 = table('RowNames',sentence)
```

How to make like this (Words that dont belong in the master_table like "simon", "haha" have value 1, so it wont affects the calculation of the probabilities to determine the class) :

```
                                    actual %determines the value based on probabilities from each words%        non_actual               class
finn marceline naptr                0.5 * 0.75 * 0.532                                                         0.5 * 0.25 * 0.468        compares the value from each class. if actual > non_actual then the class should be "actual"
jake finn simon marceline haha      0.4 * 0.5 * 1 * 0.25 * 1                                                   0.6 * 0.5 * 1 * 0.75 * 1
jake finn finn jake iceking
bmo shelby shelby finn naptr
naptr naptr jake finn bmo shelby
```

And how to make the VSM (vector space model) from the problem above:

```
                                                                        WORDS                                   
                                    | bmo | finn | jake | iceking | haha | marceline | naptr | shelby | simon |     %words sorted alphabetically      
finn marceline naptr                   0     1       0        0       0        1         1       0       0      
jake finn simon marceline haha         0     1       1        0       1        1         0       0       1
jake finn finn jake iceking            0     2       2        1       0        0         0       0       0
bmo shelby shelby finn naptr           1     1       0        0       0        0         1       1       0      
naptr naptr jake finn bmo shelby       1     1       1        0       0        0         1       1       0
```

Comment: I think you can think of a loopy solution by yourself. The steps would be : 1/ Read current sentence 2/ Split the sentence into words (Have a look at `strsplit`) 3/ Get the index of each word from your sentence in `word` (Have a look at `ismember`)

Comment: thanks for your answer! but i dont know the syntax. i already did look at ismember but i just dont know the syntax to perform that. could you please explain with syntax?

Comment: `ismember(A,B)` Will return an array the same size than `A` with `1s` where elements of `A` are found in `B` and `0s` elsewhere

Comment: could you explain it step by step (from step 1 to 3) using syntax?

Answer (score 0):

as a quick solution following code should solve your problem:

```
% Split the sentence into single strings
s = strsplit(sentence{1});

% loop over all single strings
for i=1:length(s)
    % search for each string pattern in the words-cell
    c = strfind(words,s{i});
    % get a logical vector for getting the index of the found pattern in
    % the words-cell
    ix=cellfun('isempty', c);
    ind = find(ix == 0);

    if actual(ind) > non_actual(ind)
        % do something with actual...
    end;
end;
```

you should read the help chapters for each function used in the code: `strsplit` `strfind` `cellfun` for getting more information about how they work.

Comment: thanks. but the output is not like what i want :-( and it doesnt show the calculation from each class (0.5 * 0.75 * 0.532). im really new in Matlab, so could you explain like you explain to a child :-) i really appreciate it

Comment: can you please explain, which output you are expecting exactly? Furthermore, what have you tried so far? I think with code above, you get all the information you need.

Comment: I have tried Finn's code. and it worked like i expected. i found and error when i tried your code

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit loopy as well but i fell like performance is not an issue. I would create a bigger table first and then change the values in a loop:

```
T2 = table(ones(height(T2),1),ones(height(T2),1),repmat({''},height(T2),1),'RowNames',sentence,'VariableNames',{'actual' 'non_actual' 'outcome'});

for i=1:height(T2)
    % split the row name
    A=strsplit([T2.Properties.RowNames{i,:}]);
    actual=1; %which is neutral for multiplication
    non_actual=1; 
    for j=1:length(A)
       actual = actual *  master_table{A(j),1};
       non_actual = non_actual *  master_table{A(j),2};
    end
    %if you need those
    T2.actual(i)=actual;
    T2.non_actual(i)=non_actual;

    if actual > non_actual
        T2.outcome(i)={'actual'};
    else
        T2.outcome(i)={'non_actual'};
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have updated the question because I realized the new conditions just recently, Could you please try again?